# com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser NoClassFoundException On OpenTSDB Starting

Tags: opentsdb

I compiled OPENTSDB 3.0 from source using maven and started tsd by command bin/tsdb tsd as document guide,  then failed with this exception.
the stack trace is as follow

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Failed to load plugins for type [interface net.opentsdb.configuration.provider.ProviderFactory] and namespace [net.opentsdb]
    at net.opentsdb.utils.PluginLoader.loadPlugins(PluginLoader.java:279)
    at net.opentsdb.utils.PluginLoader.loadPlugins(PluginLoader.java:193)
    at net.opentsdb.configuration.Configuration.loadPlugins(Configuration.java:1247)
    at net.opentsdb.configuration.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:289)
    at net.opentsdb.configuration.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:222)
    at net.opentsdb.tsd.TSDMain.main(TSDMain.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath$ClassInfo.load(ClassPath.java:328)
    at net.opentsdb.utils.PluginLoader.loadPlugins(PluginLoader.java:255)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 19 more
```

i have really spent a hard time compiling the source for its only support to jdk1.8 by now but i am on the java 11 env, after adapting the java version, compilation got successful result, but can't be
started for the NoClassFoundException about protobuf. By checking pom.xml, dependency on protobuf-java is there. what's the fault I have made?
really appreciated for any ideas and comments